# Cyclic representations on $C(X)$: if $\pi_\mu\oplus\pi_\nu$ is cyclic, then $\mu\perp\nu$

Tags: c-star-algebras

I'm using the definitions/conventions of $C^*$-algebras and their representations from Conway's Functional Analysis (VIII.5). If I need to supplement any definition, let me know.

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Let $\mu$ be a positive Borel measure on $X$. Then
$$
\pi_\mu:C(X)\to \mathscr B(L^2(X,\mu)),\phi\mapsto(f\mapsto \phi\cdot f)
$$
defines a representation. I've shown that this representation is cyclic. I've also shown that if $\nu$ is another positive Borel measure on $X$, then $\mu\perp\nu$ implies that $\pi_\mu\oplus\pi_\nu\cong \pi_{\mu+\nu}$, which is cyclic.

> I want to show that it goes the other way around too: if $\pi_\mu\oplus\pi_v\cong\pi_{\tau}$ where $\tau$ is a pos. Borel measure on $X$, then $\mu\perp\nu$.

*Attempt 1:*

Say $\pi_\mu\oplus\pi_n$ is cyclic with cyclic vector $(e,f)$. Arguing by contradiction, if $\pi\not\perp\mu$, then we should be able to find $(g_1,g_2)\in L^2(X,\mu)\oplus L^2(X,\nu)$ such that no net of the form $(\phi_i e,\phi_i f)$ converges to $(g_1,g_2)$. Problem is that $\mu$ and $\nu$ not being mutually singular doesn't yield the existence of an interesting set, rather it says that no interesting set exists (namely, no $A\subset X$ such that $\mu(A)=0,\nu(X-A)=0$), so I don't think I could argue here with indicator functions or something.

*Attempt 2*:

Since $\pi_\mu\oplus\pi_\nu$ is cyclic with cyclic vector $(e,f)$, it corresponds to the positive linear functional $f$ on $C(X)$ defined by
$$
f:\phi\mapsto \langle \phi f,f\rangle+\langle \phi g,g\rangle=\int \phi f\overline f d\mu+\int \phi g\overline g d\nu.
$$
By Riesz representation this functional corresponds to a positive Radon measure $\tau$:
$$
f(\phi)=\int \phi d\tau.
$$
If $\mu$ and $\nu$ are Radon (which I think is a fair assumption), then I believe this implies that $f\overline f \mu+g\overline g\nu=\tau$. Does this yield something interesting?

*Attempt 3:*

I know that any cyclic representation on $C(X)$ is of the form $\pi_\tau$ for some Radon measure $\tau$. Thus if we write $\pi_\mu\oplus\pi_\nu\cong \pi_\tau$, and we argue by contradiction, I would hope to show that the isomorphism $\Phi$ from $\pi_\tau$ to $\pi_\mu\oplus \pi_\nu$ is the same as for the case where $\mu\perp\nu$, namely
$$
f\mapsto (f,f)
$$
which I can then show is not surjective. If $\tau$ is a finite measure, then the constant functions are $\tau$-integrable, and since $\Phi$ is a morphism between representations, we would get
$$
\Phi(f)=\Phi(f\cdot 1)=f\cdot\Phi(1)
$$
for any continuous $f$. Since $\Phi=(\Phi_1,\Phi_2)$ is surjective, this shows that $\Phi_1(1)\neq 0 $ a.e. [$\mu$] and $\Phi_2(1)\neq 0$ a.e. [$\nu$], hence $\Phi_i(1)$ are cyclic vectors. Since $\tau$ is a Radon measure, $C(X)$ lies dense in $L^ 2(\tau)$ by Lusin's Theorem. This could potentially be useful?

Answer (score 1):

I will write $H_{\tau} := L^2(X,\tau)$ and denote the representation of $C(X)$ on $L^2(X,\tau)$ by multiplication operators by $\pi_{\tau}$ whenever $\tau$ is a Borel measure on $X$.  I assume you know that each $\pi_{\tau}$ is a cyclic representation of $C(X)$ and that any cyclic representation of $C(X)$ is unitarily equivalent to some $\pi_{\tau}$ (the form of your question suggests this).  To focus on the core ideas I sketch details only in "footnotes."  The conceptual key is that if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are not mutually singular, there is a nonzero measure $\sigma$ with $\sigma \ll \mu$ and $\sigma \ll \nu$.<sup>1</sup>

One approach is by analyzing commutants.  In general, $\tau$ is any measure and $\tau' \ll \tau$, the $L^2$ space $H_{\tau}$ contains a subspace isomorphic to $H_{\tau'}$,<sup>2</sup> such that an isometry implementing this isomorphism also implements a unitary equivalence between $\pi_{\tau'}$ and a subrepresentation of $\pi_{\tau}$.<sup>3</sup> So if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are not mutually singular, there is thus a nonzero $\sigma$ such that $\pi := \pi_{\mu} \oplus \pi_{\nu}$ contains a subrepresentation unitarily equivalent to $\pi_{\sigma} \oplus \pi_{\sigma}$,<sup>4</sup> and it suffices to show that $\pi_{\sigma} \oplus \pi_{\sigma}$ is not cyclic.<sup>5</sup>  But the commutant of any cyclic representation of $C(X)$ is abelian<sup>6</sup> while the commutant of $\pi(C(X))$ in $\mathcal{B}(H_{\sigma} \oplus H_{\sigma})$ clearly is not.<sup>7</sup>  End of proof.

Some language from representation theory is helpful here.  A representation $\tau$ of a $C^*$-algebra is said to be "multiplicity-free" if it contains no subrepresentation unitarily equivalent to a representation of the form $\tau' \oplus \tau'$, where $\tau'$ is a nonzero representation.  While the representations $\pi_{\tau}$ of $C(X)$ are all multiplicity-free<sup>8</sup>, the argument above shows that when $\mu$ and $\nu$ are not mutually singular, the $\pi_{\mu} \oplus \pi_{\nu}$ is *not* multiplicity-free.  (I am not sure if this perspective or language appears in Conway, but see e.g. Arveson's *Invitation to $C^*$-algebras* for more from this perspective.)

As an alternative to analyzing commutants, one can also simply exhibit nonzero vectors in the orthocomplements of the spaces $\pi(C(X)) \xi$ when the measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ are not mutually singular.  As before, we will use the existence of a nonzero measure $\sigma$ with $\sigma \ll \mu$ and $\sigma \ll \nu$.

For motivation, consider the example of $X$ finite and discrete, with $\mu$ and $\nu$ counting measures on subsets $E$ and $F$ of $X$ respectively<sup>9</sup>; such representations $\mu$ and $\nu$ are plainly mutually singular iff $E$ and $F$ are disjoint.  By indexing the elements of $E$ and $F$, one can identify $H_{\mu}$ with $\mathbb{C}^{|E|}$ and $H_{\nu}$ with $\mathbb{C}^{|F|}$ and the action of $\pi$ on $H := \mathbb{C}^{|E|+|F|}$ is by diagonal matrices, where the diagonal entries of $f \in C(X)$ list the values of $f$ first on $E$ and then on $F$.  If $E$ and $F$ are disjoint (i.e., if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are mutually singular), the image of $\pi$ is easily seen to be the set of *all* diagonal matrices, and as you already know, this representation is cyclic.<sup>10</sup> If $E$ and $F$ are not disjoint (i.e., if $\mu$ and $\nu$ fail to be mutually singular), equally clear is that the the image of $\pi$ is *not* the set of all diagonal matrices, but a subspace of diagonal matrices having some fixed pair of entries equal to one another.<sup>11</sup>  Fixing indices $1 \leq m \leq |E| < n \leq |E| + |F|$ with the property that the $m$th and $n$th diagonal entries of each matrix $\pi(f)$ are equal, let $\xi \in H$ be given.  If $\xi_m$ (resp. $\xi_n$ ) happens to be zero, then the $m$th standard basis vector $e_m$ (resp. the $n$th standard basis vector $e_n$) is nonzero and in $[\pi(C(X))\xi]^{\perp}$,<sup>12</sup> while if both $\xi_m$ and $\xi_n$ are nonzero, then the nonzero vector $\bar{\xi_m}^{-1} e_m - \bar{\xi_n}^{-1} e_n$ is in $[\pi(C(X))\xi]^{\perp}$.<sup>13</sup> So we can see very concretely how $\pi$ fails to be cyclic when $E$ and $F$ are not mutually singular in this case.

With some care, the approach just outlined extends to the general case.  Fix a nonzero $\sigma$ with $\sigma \ll \mu$ and $\sigma \ll \nu$ and let $h_{\sigma,\mu}$ and $h_{\sigma,\nu}$ respectively denote the Radon-Nikodym derivatives of $\sigma$ with respect to $\mu$ and $\nu$, and let $\xi = (\xi_1, \xi_2) \in H := H_{\mu} \oplus H_{\nu}$ be given.  If $\xi_1$ (resp. $\xi_2$) vanishes on a set of positive $\sigma$-measure, $\xi_1$ (resp. $\xi_2$) then also vanishes on a set of positive measure $P$ for which $1_P h_{\sigma,\mu}$ is in $L^2(\mu)$, and the vector $(1_P h_{\sigma,\mu},0)$ (resp. $(0,1_P h_{\sigma,\nu})$) is then seen to be a nonzero vector in $[\pi(C(X)) \xi]^{\perp}$.<sup>14</sup>  Similarly, if both $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ are nonzero almost everywhere, there is $c > 0$ for which the set $\{x \in X: \text{$|\xi_1| \geq c$ and $|\xi_2| \geq c$}\}$ has positive $\sigma$-measure, and a subset $P$ of this set, also of positive $\sigma$-measure, for which $(1_P \bar{\xi_1}^{-1} h_{\sigma,\mu}, -1_P \bar{\xi_2}^{-1} h_{\sigma,\nu})$ is in $H$, where it is seen to be a nonzero vector<sup>15</sup> in $[\pi(C(X)) \xi]^{\perp}$.<sup>16</sup>

1. This follows, for example, from a "Lebesgue decomposition"-type theorem, where I use quotes and the indefinite article because textbooks formulate these slightly differently and sometimes use different names for them.  Examples of such are [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35534/generalisation-of-lebesgue-decomposition-theorem) (the "Background" statement), [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4538989/a-proof-of-lebesgues-decomposition-theorem) (discussing a proof of one aspect of this type of theorem and referencing two other MSE posts about Lebesgue decompositions).
2. If $h$ denotes the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\tau'$ with respect to $\tau$, the relevant isometry $H_{\tau'} \to H_{\tau}$ is given by the recipe $\xi \mapsto \sqrt{h} \xi$ (short exercise to check that this is well defined).
3. The most substantive part of this might be the fact that the range of the isometry in (2) is a reducing subspace for the operators in $\pi_{\tau}(C(X))$.  One way of seeing this is to note that if $A$ is any Borel subset of $X$, the range of "multiplication by the indicator function of $A$" on $H_{\tau}$ is clearly reducing for $\pi_{\tau}(C(X))$, and to note/verify that the range of the isometry from (2) has this form, where $A$ can be taken to be the subset $\{x \in X: h(x) > 0\}$ (where $h$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative from (2); $h$ and $A$ are defined only up to a set of $\tau$-measure zero, but because of the identifications made in the space $H_{\tau}$, any choice will do).
4. Follows from (1) and two uses of (3).
5. It is immediate from the definition of "cyclic" that if $\pi'$ on $K \subseteq H$ is a subrepresentation of $\pi$ on $H$, and $\pi$ is cyclic, then $\pi'$ is also cyclic (the orthogonal projection onto $K$ of any cyclic vector for $\pi$ is a cyclic vector for $\pi'$).
6. A cyclic representation of $C(X)$ has the form $\pi_{\tau}$ for some measure $\tau$, and the commutant of $\pi_{\tau}(C(X))$ on $H_{\tau}$ is $L^{\infty}(X,\tau)$.  The closest I can find on MSE is [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2541462/showing-that-if-an-operator-commutes-with-all-multiplication-operator-it-must-b) (identifying the commutant of $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ in $\mathcal{B}(L^2(\mathbb{R})$). A similar argument shows that any operator on $L^2(X,\tau)$ that commutes with all multiplication operators in $C(X)$ is in $L^{\infty}(X,\tau)$.  It is also possible to see that the commutant of $\pi_{\tau}(C(X))$ must be abelian in a way that does not directly identify what it is.  See [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1822509/a-in-bh-a-unital-abelian-c-algebra-with-cyclic-vector-then-a-is-abeli) (showing that a unital abelian $C^*$-subalgebra of $\mathcal{B}(H)$ with a cyclic vector necessarily has an abelian commutant).
7. For example, a short calculations show that the operator on $H_{\sigma} \oplus H_{\sigma}$ given by $(\xi_1, \xi_2) \mapsto (\xi_2,0)$ and its adjoint $(\xi_1,\xi_2) \mapsto (0, \xi_1)$, which do not commute, are in the commutant of $\pi_{\sigma} \oplus \pi_{\sigma}$.  (More generally, thinking of elements of $H_{\sigma}$ as $2 \times 1$ "column vectors," one can locate a copy of $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ in the commutant of $\pi_{\sigma} \oplus \pi_{\sigma}$.)
8. Conway hopefully proves this, or at least gives some idea of why it is true.  Being multiplicity-free is equivalent to having an image whose commutant is abelian, so this statement amounts to an identification of $\pi_{\tau}(C(X))'$ in $H_{\tau}$ (see point (6)).  A book might naturally do this near a discussion of the GNS representation, or in a discussion of abelian von Neumann algebras.
9. There is actually no loss of generality (within the world of finite and discrete $X$) in assuming that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are counting measures, because any measure on a finite and discrete $X$ is mutually absolutely continuous with respect to a unique counting measure.  [In general, when one replaces a measure $\tau$ with another that is mutually absolutely continuous with respect to it, the unitary equivalence class of $\pi_{\tau}$ does not change.  The details of this are similar to points (1), (2) above.]
10. Any vector in $H$ with all entries nonzero will be cyclic for $\pi$ in this case, as also holds in general. See generally e.g. [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/972902/cyclic-representation-on-l2-mu) (identifying all cyclic vectors for $L^{\infty}(\mu)$ acting on $L^2(\mu)$).
11. If $E$ and $F$ are not disjoint, when listing the values of any $f \in C(X)$ first on $E$ and then on $F$, a value will repeat in that list for each element of $E$ that is also an element of $F$, and these values will repeat in the same places for every $f \in C(X)$.
12. The desired orthogonality comes from the fact that the pointwise product of any $f\xi$ with the conjugate of the given vector is zero.
13. The desired orthogonality comes from the fact that the pointwise product of any $f\xi$ with the conjugate of the given vector has $m$th entry $f(p)$, $n$th entry $-f(p)$, and all other entries $0$ (here $p$ is the point of $E \cap F$ corresponding to the indices $m$ and $n$).
14. Starting with any set $P$ of positive $\sigma$-measure on which $|\xi_j| = 0$, we can additionally assume that $1_P h_{\sigma,\mu}$ is in $H_{\mu}$ (when a priori it is only, like $h_{\sigma,\mu}$ itself, in $L^1(X,\mu)$) by replacing $P$ with $\{p \in P: h_{\sigma,\mu} \leq n\}$ for $n$ sufficiently large (any such has the property that the vector constructed from it will be in $L^2(\mu)$, and these sets have positive $\sigma$-measure for $n$ sufficiently large).  The element of $H$ thus constructed is nonzero because its norm in $H$ is $\sigma(P)$.  The desired orthogonality follows from the same facts as in the discrete case (12).
15. The point of "$c$" is to ensure that the functions $\xi_1^{-1}$ and $\xi_2^{-1}$ are bounded on $P$.  The subset $P$ can be chosen of the form $\{x \in X: |\xi_1| \geq c, |\xi_2| \geq c, h_{\sigma,\mu} \leq n, h_{\sigma,\nu} \leq n\}$ (any such set has the property that the vector constructed from $P$ is in both $L^2(\mu)$ and $L^2(\nu)$, and $P$ will have positive $\sigma$-measure for $n$ sufficiently large).
    The vector thus constructed is nonzero in $H_{\mu}$ e.g. because the inner product of its $H_{\mu}$ component with $\xi_1$ is $\sigma(P) \neq 0$.
16. The desired orthogonality comes from the fact that the pointwise product of any $f \xi_1$ with the conjugate of the $H_{\mu}$ component of the given vector is $f 1_P h_{\sigma,\mu}$, while the pointwise product of $\xi_2$ with the conjugate of the $H_{\nu}$ component of the given vector is  $f 1_P h_{\sigma,\nu}$.  It follows the inner product of any $\pi(f)(\xi)$ with the constructed vector is $\int_P f h_{\sigma,\mu} \, d\mu - \int_P f h_{\sigma,\nu} \, d\nu = \int_P f \, d\sigma - \int_P f \, d\sigma = 0$. This is the same idea as the discrete case (13), with the two copies of $L^2(X,\sigma)$ inside $L^2(X,\mu)$ and $L^2(X,\nu)$ playing the roles of the indices $m$ and $n$ in the finite case. Very roughly speaking, they are distinct "locations" within $H$ where we can leverage the fact that the corresponding "diagonal entries" of the operators $\pi(C(X))$ are constrained to be equal to one another.